# How prove that there are $a,b,c$ such that $a \in A, b \in B, c \in C$ and $a,b,c$ (with approriate order) is a arithmetic sequence?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, arithmetic-combinatorics

Let $N=\{ 1,2,3,..., 3n \}$ with $n$ is a positive integer and $A,B,C$ are three arbitrary sets such that $A \cup B \cup C = N, A \cap B = B \cap C = C \cap A = \varnothing, |A| = |B| = |C| = n $.
How prove that there are $a,b,c$ such that $a \in A, b \in B, c \in C$  and $a,b,c$ (with approriate order)  is a arithmetic sequence?

Comment: The "arithmetic sequence" part is confusing (because it could be in any order), I'd say "How to prove there exists $a,b,c$ such that one of them is the average of the others?".

Answer (score 2):

This was a conjecture posed by Rados Radocic Which was proven independently by by [Radocic and Veselin Jungic](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/EMIS/journals/INTEGERS/papers/d18/d18.pdf) in 2003 and by [Maria Axenovich and Dimitri von der Flass](http://www.combinatorics.org/Volume_11/PDF/v11i1r1.pdf) in 2004.

Comment: Those proofs are surprisingly complicated. I would hate to be asked to verify them, or put them in a proof-checking system.

Comment: Well yeah, I tried to find a simple solution for a a couple of days but couldn't. So I'm afraid giving these links is the best I can do.

Comment: If the proofs are like those, then, yeah.

Comment: I actually like those proofs a lot. It makes me feel as if the fact they are hard to grasp makes them deeper.