# Partitioning Integers into Equal Sets to Guarantee Arithmetic Progression

Tags: combinatorics, ramsey-theory

I've run into the following problem which I am sure is true but I cannot prove it:

> If we color the integers in the set $S = \{1, 2, \ldots, 3n \}$ with $3$ colors such that each color is used $n$ times, there always exist integers $a,b,c \in S$ with distinct colors such that they are in arithmetic progression.

This seems related to Van der Waerden's theorem but we are looking at integers with different colors. Also the fact that we are using $3$  colors $n$ times and are looking at $3n$ integers suggests that this problem may be generalized. Any insights will be appreciated.

Comment: This is a duplicate of a question, although that question does not have answers http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/939032/how-prove-that-there-are-a-b-c-such-that-a-in-a-b-in-b-c-in-c-and-a-b. You probably found this question in mathlinks, I posted it there trying to find a solution to post here :)

Comment: @JorgeFernández Yes, I visit it sometimes and I found your post and was really intrigued. I guess this will have to be closed now.

Comment: No, apparently questions must only be closed if there is an equivalent question which has with either accepted or upvoted answers

Answer (score 1):

In:

Rainbow 3-term Arithmetic Progressions

by Veselin Jungić
in Integers, the Electronic Journal of Combinatorial Number Theory, volume 3

we have this abstract:

Consider a coloring of {1, 2,...,n} in 3 colors, where n ≡ 0 (mod 3). If all the color classes have the same cardinality, then there is a 3-term arithmetic progression whose elements are colored in distinct colors. This rainbow variant of van der Waerden’s theorem proves the conjecture of the second author.

Which seems to answer your question. This information is [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.113.6985).